# ordenar datos de select

Tags: php, html, laravel, vue.js, vuejs

tengo este select, en el cual estoy colocando tres datos en cada item del select.

```
<div class="col-4">
     <div class="form-group row no-gutters mb-1">
          <label class="col-sm-7 col-form-label col-form-label-sm pr-1 text-right">Distrito</label>
          <div class="col-5">
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm" v-model="organizacion[0].c_ubig">
                  <option v-bind:value="ubigeo.c_ubig" v-for="ubigeo in ubig">
                  <tr>
                      <td>{{ ubigeo.l_ubig }}</td>
                      &nbsp; &nbsp;
                      <td>{{ ubigeo.l_prov }}</td>
                      &nbsp; &nbsp;
                      <td>{{ ubigeo.l_depa }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  </option>
          </select>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

el cual me da como resultado lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven los datos estan desordenados y lo que deseo es ordenarlos,como si fuera una tabla,

como se muestra el la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si traes los datos desde una consulta a `MySQL` por ejemplo, lo puedes hacer con `order by distrito desc` o con `order by distrito asc`. Esta cláusula la puedes agregar al final de la consulta.

Comment: Como dice @DjCrazy, ordená desde el backend. Publicá la consulta que estás haciendo con Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto lo puede hacer con la función 'sort', en la parte de tu código en donde estes asignando el valor a tu variable 'ubig' puedes hacer esto:

```
this.ubig.sort(function(a, b) {
   if (a.l_ubig.toLowerCase() > b.l_ubig.toLowerCase()) {
     return 1;
   } else {
     return -1;
   }
});
```

Esto ordenara tu arreglo alfabéticamente usando el campo 'l_ubig' de cada objeto.